# Possible to hide Parse Logo at Login?

Tags: parse-platform

Is there any chance to hide the logo from Parse at login when using Parse as backend-service, e.g. paying a fee to Parse or via any settings?

Right now I am using iOS and the Swift-Template from Parse.com

Comment: could you edit the question and add some more info? maybe describe the scenario a little bit more?

Comment: Also, what is the front end you're using where the logo is actually displayed...

Comment: see infos at edited post

Comment: You're seeing the logo because it's a template project to demo Parse functionality. Parse does not require its logo to be displayed or their services mentioned anywhere in the app - doesn't matter if the app is at the free tier